# C# reading document from mongodb into JSON and trying to get values

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, parsing

I am new to JSON so this may be a simple question.  I have the code below (with a json object, again below).

I just want to be able to read the JSON and put items from it into variables to be readable.

Error I am receiving and it is due to the text `ObjectID("")` in the JSON object being returned:
`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: O. Path '_id', line 1, position 10.`

JSON object as returned from MONGO:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("543c2d426b6b5ef78b62fc41"),
    "LoanStatusAddedEvent": {
        "@From": "Lakewood",
        "@MessageTimeDateStamp": "2013-08-12T05:03:23.035-04:00",
        "@MessageID": "29055040",
        "LoanNumber": "5300494930",
        "CurrentIndicator": "true",
        "StatusChangeDate": "2013-08-11T20:01:01.000",
        "StatusValue": "42",
        "StatusType": "Active"
    }
}
```

Code:

```
        // connect to the mongo server and the Mongos DB
        string connectionString = "connectionstringhere";


        MongoServer mongo = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
        mongo.Connect();

        MongoDatabase database = mongo.GetDatabase("Mangos");


        //Builds new Collection (looking at JsonImports on server)
        MongoCollection<LoanStatus> collection2 = database.GetCollection<LoanStatus>("JsonImports");


        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("JsonImports");


        var query = new QueryDocument(); //("LoanNumber", "5300494930");


        foreach (BsonDocument item in collection.Find(query))
        {
            string json = item.ToJson();

            Console.WriteLine(item);


            // code here to below http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm
            JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

            string rssLoanNumber = (string)rss["LoanStatusAddedEvent"]["LoanNumber"];

            Console.WriteLine(rssLoanNumber);



        }// end for each loop


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Read();


public class LoanStatus
{
    public string From { get; set; }

    public string MessageTimeDateStamp { get; set; }

    public string MessageID { get; set; }

    public string LoanNumber { get; set; }

    public string CurrentIndicator { get; set; }

    public string StatusChangeDate { get; set; }

    public string StatusValue { get; set; }

    public string StatusType { get; set; }

    //public string id { get; set; }



    public void PrintDetailsToScreen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                            this.LoanNumber, this.StatusChangeDate, this.StatusValue));
    }

}

public class RootObject
{
    public LoanStatus LoanStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object should have a `Field` or `Property` with the name `_id` or `Id` of type `ObjectId`.

```
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
```

If you can rebulid your mongo database you could change type of `Id` to `String` instead of `ObjectId`
and tell mongo driver to treat all id as string by

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterIdGenerator(typeof(string), new StringObjectIdGenerator());
```

If you do this, you can use any `string` as `Id` and if its empty the MongoDb create a random `Id` for your document

- Updated:

A Mongodb Docuemnt is not a valid Json document. It has some values that is not gonna parsed with json.net.
You should manually remove them. there is simple code for that

```
var json = "ObjectId(\"123\")";
var result =  Regex.Match(json, @"ObjectId\(([^\)]*)\)").Value;
var id = result.Replace("ObjectId(", string.Empty).Replace(")", String.Empty);
var validJson = json.Replace(result, id);
```

Comment: The objectId is autogenerated when inserting records into the DB.  Here is the JSON before importing into Mongo:

{"LoanStatusAddedEvent":{"@From":"Lakewood","@MessageTimeDateStamp":"2013-08-12T05:03:24.602-04:00","@MessageID":"29056324","LoanNumber":"4699880107","CurrentIndicator":"true","StatusChangeDate":"2013-08-12T00:36:23.000","StatusValue":"45","StatusType":"Active"}}

Comment: Mongo Json is not a standard Json that json.net understands. String Id will solve the problem but maybe not with the way you wanted.

Comment: I dont need or care about the id field (at least in the results) so is there a way to ignore it and make it work as a JSON object?

Or some other way to parse out the record from MongoDB other then JSON.  I dont have to use JSON to parse it out.

Comment: You could manually replace ObjectID("...") with "..." with Regex. 
            var json = "ObjectId(\"123\")";
            var result =  Regex.Match(json, @"ObjectId\(([^\)]*)\)").Value;
            var id = result.Replace("ObjectId(", string.Empty).Replace(")", String.Empty);
            var validJson = json.Replace(result, id);

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like that (the replace function) but I could have hundreds of results returned (not the majority of the time though) and was not sure of the performance impact, but I was just going to do a string replace, the regex will be much faster.

Do you know what kind of performance hit it would take with the example JSON above assuming hundreds of records (I know a lot of other factors are considered but a ballpark)

Comment: I have tested the above example with 10,000 entries, and it took 13 ms for it to finish. But I still recommend the Custom Serialization method, since it follows good programming paradigms, and additionally makes your code cleaner.

Comment: It looks like the regex is working and it removes the "ObjectID(" from the object, but it is not removing the trailing ")" that follows the opening.

I tweaked the code to do the below, do you think this could cause any issues?
json.Replace(result + ")", id);

Comment: Code will remove **ObjectId(** in first replace and **)** in second replcae: result.Replace("ObjectId(", string.Empty).Replace(")", String.Empty). Just remember the regex section is necessary in code above because your json may have more **ObjectId(** and **)** in it; I tested the code with many example, its working, I wonder why its not working for you ...!

Comment: Thats what I thought it would do by looking at it, when I ran it I got an error for the extra ")", I added the replace and it worked.  I will have to retry some more to see if I am missing something or what.

Comment: At last it was a solution for you or not?